# Get third element of tuple

Tags: haskell

I have a tuple (1, 2, 3) and want to get the third element, however, I keep getting type errors.

Please see the below code:

```
third (hd : tl) = snd tl
third tpl = head$tail$tail tpl
```

How can I fix the type errors that are occuring and get the third element correctly?

Comment: third (_,_c) = c ?
Can't make any sense of your code, head and tail are for list, and : is list constructor

Answer (score 3):

**Tuples aren't lists**

In you're code, you're manipulating lists, `:`, `head` and `tail` all work on lists. So

```
third tpl = head . tail . tail . tail $ tpl
third' (_:_:x:_) = x
```

Will give you the third element.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

>> third a
   3
>> third (1, 2, 3)
   Error expecting list, but got tuple
```

Instead you're going to have to use a function of type

```
thd :: (a, b, c) -> c
```

This function doesn't exist in the standard libs, it's completely trivial

```
thd (_, _, a) = a
```

And that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting tuples confused with lists:

```
-- Tuples: Fixed length, mixed types, uses parenthesis
myTuple :: (Int, String)
myTuple = (1, "Hello")

-- Lists: Variable length, single type, uses square brackets
myList :: [Int]
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

-- Pattern matching a 3-tuple
isRightTriangle :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
isRightTriangle (a, b, c) = a^2 + b^2 == c^2

-- Pattern matching a 2-tuple
name :: (String, Int) -> String
name (n, a) = n
-- or: name = fst

age :: (String, Int) -> Int
age (n, a) = a
-- or: age = snd

-- Pattern matching a list
thirdElem :: [a] -> a
thirdElem (x1:x2:x3:xs) = x3
thirdElem _ = error "List must have at least 3 elements"
-- or: thirdElem xs = head $ tail $ tail xs
```

If you haven't already, you should check out [Learn You a Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#ready-set-go).  It's a great, fun to read introduction to Haskell, starting out with the basic types like strings, tuples, numbers, and lists.